# Android: onFling won't to call

Tags: android

I have a simple list activity, for each list item I have onTouchEventListener class defined.

The problem is onFling event never occures, instead of it following sequence of events:
onDown, onShowPress, onLongPress. When I do the same but assign onTouchEventListener to the ListView instance then onFling happens as well but not when I assign it to the list items :(

Any thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts are why don't you post your code.

Answer (score 3):

Because of a possible bug, onDown method is needed to return true to make sure, that other events also occur. Thus, make sure your custom onDown always returns true.

Comment: Great! I was wondering about this for hours and could not find why onFling would not fire. Always returning true for onDown worked like a charm.